# Sharing objects between class loader using serialization

Tags: java, serialization, classloader

I have a test that load some modules of the project in a custom class loader (for testing purposes).
One of the method in such object gets custom object as argument, and if i'm passing it from the test class (which has been loaded by the default classloader), to method in an object that was loaded by my custom class loader i'm getting type mismatch exception.

I have thought i can avoid this issue because fortunately my custom object implements Serializable (I thought to serilizae the object from the test class and then deserialize it in my custom classloader and pass it to the method).
However, since the serilization utils classes loaded by the parent class loader, the produced object (deserialization output) is still pointed from the default class loader.

How can I deserialize the object in the custom class loader? 
The code:

```
Class<?> serialClassDefinition = classLoader.loadClass("org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils");
        final byte[] serializedDestData = SerializationUtils.serialize(sampleData);
        final Method deSerializeMethod = serialClassDefinition.getDeclaredMethod("deserialize", byte[].class);
        final Object oldSmapleData = deSerializeMethod.invoke(null, serializedSampleData);
        return (invoke(stringA, stringB, stringC, oldSampleData, isAAA));
```

Comment: Type mismatches as you have described should not happen with a well designed custom classloader. And serialization is not a good workaround for that design problem. Did you chain the custom classloader to the correct parent? Are you delegating `loadClass` calls to the parent classloader first?

Comment: I'm doing it for backward compatability test. My own class loader loads classes from the child class loader, and search in the parent only if the class is missing. So i'm delegating load class to the parent only if the child didn't found the class

Comment: Are you doing it this way because there is a possibility that a class being tested has been updated, and you want the custom classloader to load it, as opposed to the parent?

Comment: Yes, for example one of the issue is: the server generates some file and the client needs to parse it. I need to test old client with new server so i'd like to have the old client jars (including the parser) in the custom class loader class path

Comment: Ok I figured correctly. I think this is going to be very complicated to get working the way you want. You either have to instantiate all objects to be used in the custom class loader ***via*** the custom class loader, or alternatively (and better imo) use a proven technology like OSGI to do your regression testing.